# How do I customize the tooltip in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I'd like to round the values in the tooltip for ggplotly.

I have code and when you hover over a column, it shows the full value.

I checked the docs but I had a hard time finding instructions.

This is my code

```
library(fpp)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

gg <-
    credit %>% 
        ggplot(aes(score)) +
        geom_histogram(fill = "lightblue") +
        theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "XY") +   
      labs(title = paste0("Histogram: "),
           x = "")

ggplotly(gg)
```

When I hover over one of the columns, it shows the value as the full number (60.2312).

I'd like to show the rounded version of that, so it shows 60 instead

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved by mapping a formatted string on the `text` aesthetic, e.g. to show the `score` with no digits you could use `paste("score:", scales::number(score, accuracy = 1))`. As this adds another entry in the tooltip you have to add option `tooltip = list("text", "count")` to prevent the default entry for `score`:

```
library(fpp)
library(plotly)

gg <-
  credit %>% 
  ggplot(aes(score)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(text = paste("score:", scales::number(score, accuracy = 1))), fill = "lightblue") +
  labs(title = paste0("Histogram: "),
       x = "")

ggplotly(gg, tooltip = list("text", "count"))
```

[image]